# Is it possible to take the screenshot of URL using html2canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html2canvas

Below code is taking the screenshot of the current page. Is it possible to take the screenshot of the URL in html2canvas? I mean I have a URL which is

```
mydomain.com/home
mydomain.com/home?id=2
mydomain.com/home/2
```

Now how to take the screenshot and display the screenshot image on another page?

```js
window.takeScreenShot = function() {
    html2canvas(document.getElementById("target"), {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        },
        width:320,
        height:220
    });
}
```

```css
#target{
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    background:blue;
    color:#fff;
    padding:10px;
}
button{
    display:block;
    height:20px;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="target">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque quis eleifend elit. Donec lectus sem, scelerisque sit amet facilisis quis, gravida a lacus. Nunc at lorem egestas, gravida lorem quis, pulvinar ante. Quisque id tempus libero. Mauris hendrerit nunc risus, ac laoreet lectus gravida et. Nam euismod magna ac enim posuere sagittis. Fusce at egestas enim, eu hendrerit enim.
</div>

<button onclick="takeScreenShot()">to image</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/build/html2canvas.js"></script>
```

Comment: It will be good for me to share the reason for close this question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an iframe to load your other document, on its load event call html2canvas with the iframe's `contentDocument.documentElement` and voilà.

**[of course, this will work only with same-origin documents]**

```js
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.src = YOUR_SAME_DOMAIN_URL_HERE
iframe.onload = function(e) {   
  // note: this assumes html2canvas v5+
   html2canvas(iframe.contentDocument.documentElement).then(function(canvas){
     document.body.removeChild(iframe);
     doSomethingWithTheCanvas(canvas);
    });
}
// just to hide the iframe
iframe.style.cssText ='position: absolute; opacity:0; z-index: -9999';
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

**[As a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uggmnho5/4/)** since StackSnippet's null origin iframe disable the access to inner iframes...

Comment: I am not able to understand the output of the fiddle.

Comment: Well what's in the output is the canvas result of html2canvas function. What don't you understand?

Comment: It's not talking the screenshot. It's displaying only text.

Comment: How do I use your above code? I just entered the URL in this line iframe.src = YOUR_SAME_DOMAIN_URL_HERE but nothing is happening

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158575/discussion-between-narendra-verma-and-kaiido).